# Angular 5: Google Picker and navigate break target component

Tags: angular, google-api, google-picker

I have a problem with Google Picker inside an Angular 5 app.

Into the picker callback I hide the picker and then navigate to another page.
But target page loads strangely: some elements of the previous page is still there and new elements is showed partially. After some seconds or after a manual page reload everything looks good.
It seems that the html injected by Google Picker breaks something.

Here my picker callback:

```
onPickerChosen(data: any) {
  const action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
  if (action === google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
    this.picker.setVisible(false);
    this.router.navigate(['/home'], { replaceUrl: true });
  } else if (action === google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
    this.picker.setVisible(false);
    // ...
    this.router.navigate(['/map-edit', googleFileId]);
  }
}
```

Have I to dispose something? (I tried also with `this.picker.dispose()`).
Can someone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved in a bad way but it works: forcing Angular refresh before page changing.

So:

```
this.router.navigate(['/home'], { replaceUrl: true });
```

becomes:

```
this.zone.run(() => {
  this.navigate(['/home'], { replaceUrl: true });
}
```